# Spring XML namespaces : How do I get Spring XML namespaces in eclipse like that of in netbeans?

Tags: spring, eclipse, xml-namespaces

I have added images of XML namespace support in netbeans. Is there a similar one for eclipse? Perhaps a plugin or something, so that we can get namespaces in eclipse like that of in netbeans.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: ````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd"></beans>````

Comment: You mean Spring Tools Suite 3?

Comment: I'm not using STS but want to write spring programs in eclipse